# What is the best way to create a object in C# that will be re-used

Tags: c#, class, object, new-operator

I've the following class

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public bool Enabled {get;set;}

    public Car()
    {
        this.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

In my code I can create the object like below and set some properties.

```
Car oCar = new Car();

oCar.Id = 1;
oCar.Name = "FastCar";
```

I then have a separate function like below

```
public static Car MyCarTest()
{
    //do some logic....
    Car oCar = new Car();
    oCar.Id = 1;
    oCar.Name = "Very FastCar";
    oCar.Enabled = true;
    return oCar;
}
```

If I call the same code as below, followed by the function;

```
Car oCar = new Car();

oCar.Id = 1;
oCar.Name = "FastCar";

oCar  = MyCarTest();
```

On calling the function at this point it will create a new object of type Car and will assign the name as 'Very FastCar' and Enabled set to true;  The Function returns a new Car() of which is assigned to the initial Car object that was created.

- EDIT *

My question is, what is the proper way to create a object, set some properties values, and then later in your code, your conditional check means that the original object and property values that were set, will be overwritten by a new instance of the object like;

```
Car oCar = new Car();

oCar.Id = 1;
oCar.Name = "FastCar";

Car oCar1 = new Car();
oCar.Id = 1;
oCar.Name = "Very FastCar";
oCar.Enabled = true;

oCar = oCar1
```

Is this the preferred way ?

Comment: "which will assign the functions object to the initial object of Car that was created" – I don't really understand this part. Or really all of the last paragraph – can you give examples of what you mean to make it clearer? (Describing behaviour of code in prose is always fiddly, more so if English isn't your first language.)

Comment: I've added to the question.

Comment: well, you could set your properties into a contructor or Object Initializers

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a normal or abnormal way of creating an object. It is somewhat odd to create an object, change it, then immediately discard it but I assume that's just your sample code. It really all depends on what you're trying to ultimately accomplish. (This is why completely theoretical questions with made-up examples are inherently problematic.)

Comment: @millimoose Yes, this is just some sample code ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example you're actually *changing* the originally created car:

```
Car oCar = new Car();

oCar.Id = 1;
oCar.Name = "FastCar";
```

when you call:

```
oCar  = MyCarTest();
```

making the *original creation moot*. If you're wanting to build a method that returns a *default object*, then just do this:

```
var oCar  = MyCarTest();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call to MyCarTest is indeed overwriting your oCar variable, as Michael noted.  That said, what you have here

```
public static Car MyCarTest()
{
    //do some logic....
    Car oCar = new Car();
    oCar.Id = 1;
    oCar.Name = "Very FastCar";
    oCar.Enabled = true;
    return oCar;
}
```

is usually referred to as 
a factory function.  If you need to create an object with the same basic properties again and again, this is absolutely a common way to do it.

Comment: So if I created a object of type Car, set some property values and then called your function above; is it correct to just assign MyAlreadyCreatedCarObject = MyCarTest();

Answer (score 0):

In addition to:

```
Car oCar = new Car();

oCar.Id = 1;
oCar.Name = "FastCar";
```

you can also do:

```
Car oCar = new Car
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "FastCar"
};
```

Whether one way or the other is the "normal" way of doing things is a moot point. Some may prefer one way over the other, but both are valid.